# Windows CE restore other app window in C#

Tags: c#, windows-ce

How can I restore other application window from my application?
I know only process name for this application.
I search code for .Net 3.5
Thanks and hope for you reply

Comment: using .net compact framework 3.5?

Comment: Locate the Handle for the Process then move the handle to the foreground.  I have only ever done this using a Win32 dll use the WinCE version of it.

Comment: @Eren - I am sure he is considering he is using C#

Comment: Sorry, for all. I need solution for .net 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you know about that other Window, but generally speaking you could [P/Invoke to `FindWindow`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.FindWindowW) and pass in the window's caption.  That will get you the target Window's handle.  With that you call [`BringWindowToTop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452899), [`ShowWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453731) and/or [`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453662.aspx) (again via P/Invoke) depending on the Window's state and your desires.